Typescript contextual type inference inside generic function
I am designing an API for a Typescript library, and I found a design that works very well, except for one problem, that I cannot seem to solve.
Consider the following code:
const useFn = <T, U>(fn: (x: T) => U, x: T) => fn(x)

const makeFn = <T, U>(fn: (x: T) => U) => (): ((x: T) => U) => fn
useFn(
    makeFn(x => x + 1)(),
    1
)

const directFn = <T, U>(fn: (x: T) => U) => fn
useFn(
    directFn(x => x + 1),
    1
)

Now, this is a simplified example that highlights the problem I am having. I am wondering, why is it that the function types inside directFn can be inferred correctly from its context, but the inferrence fails on makeFn, meaning the function inside makeFn is being inferred as (x: unknown) => any.
My question is:
Is it possible to change the type definition of makeFn in a way, that its inner function x => x + 1 is inferred to (x: number) => number without additional type hints.
I know, it this can easily be achieved by using the makeFn different:
makeFn((x: number) => x + 1)
This is not the solution I am looking for.
I am not sure if this is possible, and maybe it isn't, in that case I would gladly accept  an answer about why it is impossible.
Thank you!

Your problem isn't really related to the generic itself, if you simply write a function const foo = x => x + 1 then the type of x is also not known. Typescript doesn't know that you think it should always be a number.

we all can see, that x should be a number And this is because?

Just because you're doing x + 1, it isn't necessarily the case that x is number. It could easily be string. The way to tell makeFn that x is a number is the way you've ruled out: By providing a type annotation for it.

The idea is that useFn is providing the context for the type inferrence. I just now realize, that I have not provided the definition for useFn yet. I have updated the question accordingly.

How does useFn have anything to do with this? I think you might have a misconception about how inference works, and how far through a program a contextual type can reach. The line const made = makeFn(x => x + 1); will always end up determining the type of made depending only on the type of makeFn. There is no information inside x => x + 1 that can be used to determine that x should be a number. The fact that later you use made in a context that assumes x was a number (although frankly this is not obvious to me) doesn't affect that. It's too late. Does that make sense?

(see prev comment) The kind of thing you want is equivalent to ms/TS#30017, which was declined. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I have updated the question in a way to highlight the problem i am trying to solve more accurately

@jcalz Thank you for the link provided! It does not hit the exact problem I'd like to solve, I hope the updated question highlights this. My apologies for changing it again, you are right about that i do not have a clear concept about what is possible and why in the typescript inference engine.

It does hit the exact problem you actually had in your original question, but now you've changed it so that it's very slightly different. But it doesn't change the main issue: TS's contextual types don't reach through an arbitrary number of syntax nodes. That's not tenable to implement and would end up making things less predictable in lots of situations. If I write an answer here it would be the same as my answer to this question: contextual typing has limits; if you hit those limits, annotate.  Does that fully address it now?

Absolutely! Reading your comment I learned that the exact problem I wanted to solve was not the exact problem I had stated.

I think we have hit what my actual question is, and this is a key part of the answer:
"TS's contextual types don't reach through an arbitrary number of syntax nodes."
And this also implies, that it is not possible to change the makeFn definition to link the types explicitly?

Pretty much. I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of the other one; I don't know that there's any more insight to be had writing up a specific answer for this. Thoughts?

I agree with that. Thanks for the help!
